# not able to import pandoc,getting FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, package, anaconda

I have installed pandoc package in the anaconda with the use of pip install pandoc but I is throwing below error .
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandoc/definitions/1.16.hs'

I have followed below link :
https://pypi.org/project/pandoc/

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error when I made the mistake of putting

```
import pandoc           # Causes the FileNotFoundError!
```

at the top of my Python script. The library is called `pypandoc`, not `pandoc`, so instead try

```
import pypandoc         # Works for me.
```